# Magento 2 Extension usage restriction for multiple project

Tags: magento2, extensions, license

I am creating an extension, but I want to restrict the extension usage in multiple projects. Like if a customer purchased the extension for one project, but he should never use the same extension to any other projects.

I heard there has a licence Key concept, but I am not much clear about the concept.So kindly share your ideas and thoughts to make the extension work only for the purchased domain

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good resource that may help https://seegatesite.com/my-way-create-license-key-for-php-application/